# How to show the VSS and VDD pins in 4033 IC (7 segement decoder)

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I am trying to make a stopwatch circuit by watching a circuit diagram (Right one is my proteus and left one is from internet) you can see on the left image that second has all the pins which are connected to other jumper wires and i dont have those pins in my proteus

[image: SS]

Comment: AFAIK you can't, it's rubbish. To decide what nets are connected to it, double click on the symbol, then click hidden pins and assign the appropriate nets to the appropriate pins. I guess otherwise you'd have to create new symbols.

Comment: @DiBosco but in left image you can see he did unhide those pins?

Comment: What makes you think it was done in proteus? It might be, I'm not being sarcastic

Comment: Why do you want to show them? They just clutter up the schematic so unless I'm doing something unusual with them I wouldn't normally bother. On a larger design they sometimes all go on a separate sheet.

Comment: @Finbarr because i want to simlutae it?

Comment: @DiBosco i am very much noob in using proteus can you tell me how can i connect them using nets?

Comment: @Finbarr you want them because when you start poking around your PCB you want to know which pins are power and ground. It's nonsense to say they clutter a design.

Comment: @DanialAhmed When you click on the hidden pins as I described you need to assign your net names. It will say something like pin Vdd, you enter the net name that you want it to connect to. It's a bananas way of doing it, but I think unless you edit your symbol, you have no choice.

Comment: @DiBosco i understand that much but problem is pin 16 of left 4033 is connected to pin 3 of right one and i dont know how to find the net for that pin 3 same goes for the pin 8 and battery

Comment: @DanialAhmed I don't understand what you mean by "find that net", sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66712/discussion-between-danial-ahmed-and-dibosco).